# Search Linked List with User Input - Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, user-input

I have created my linked list and I wish for the user to enter a Station and then the output is the number stored for that station.

```
    LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();



            myList.addFirst("London", 5);            
      myList.addNode("Manchester ", 10);

      myList.addNode("Liverpool", 20);
      myList .addNode("Birmingham", 50);
```

This is the input for the user to enter.

```
          String name;              
              name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Station: ");


   StringNode  temp;

       temp = mylist.head;

       if (temp.Station == (name)) {


           System.out.println("Yes");


       }
```

The rest of the methods are just adding a new data and printing.

Thanks

Comment: Ive tried that but for linked list that doesnt work

Comment: try it again.  temp.Station == (name) should be temp.Station.equals(name) . That's assuming Station is a String.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is what a HashMap is for.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("London", 5);            
map.put("Manchester ", 10);
map.put("Liverpool", 20);
map.put("Birmingham", 50);

String station = "Liverpool";
Integer i = map.get(station);
System.out.println(i);
```